# Android: Signing APK with ApkSigner with multi certificate

Tags: android, jarsigner, android-app-signing, apksigner

Problem is my app apk is signed with sha1 signer #1 and sha1 signer #2 using jarsigner. meaning multisigned using both first-release-key.jks and second-release-key.jks which i believe now is wrong. Apk shows both certs. Now trying to sign apk with apksigner using sha2 signer #1 and then sha2 signer #2 is failing.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner

Usually, you sign an APK using only one signer. In the event that you need to sign an APK using multiple signers, use the --next-signer option to separate the set of general options to apply to each signer:

```
apksigner sign [signer_1_options] --next-signer [signer_2_options] app-name.apk

apksigner sign --ks sample.keystore --ks-key-alias abc --ks-pass pass:xyz --key-pass pass:somepass --next-signer --ks someks.jks --ks-key-alias key0 --ks-pass pass:123456 --key-pass pass:123456 MSIGN.apk
```

When --next-signer used with above is used apksigner gets error to use "**SigningCertificateLineage**"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple signing certificates provided for use with APK Signature Scheme v3 without an accompanying SigningCertificateLineage
```

**Source code:**

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/apksig/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/apksig/SigningCertificateLineage.java

**Anyone help where to get SigningCertificateLineage and accompanying SigningCertificateLineage while using  --next-signer hence apk is multi signed?**

Thanks

Comment: _"how to accompanying SigningCertificateLineage while using --next-signer?"_ It's shown on the same page that you linked to in your question: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner#usage-rotate

Comment: Edited my question: Where to get the certificate lineage?

Comment: Also shown on the same page (near the bottom).

Comment: you mean "$ apksigner rotate --out /path/to/new/file --old-signer \ --ks release.jks --new-signer --ks release2.jks
" ?

Comment: able to get the SigningCertificateLineage with above command , how to i pass to mutisign via --new-signer ?

Comment: By using the `--lineage` option. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/apksig/+/refs/heads/master/src/apksigner/java/com/android/apksigner/help_sign.txt

Comment: Damn its not in document.. saved my day! but after using "apksigner sign --lineage MyLineage --ks first-release-key.jks --next-signer --ks second-release-key.jks app.apk" my question error is gone but.."apksigner verify" shows signer #1 info only i.e of second-release-key.js. Expectation is to show " first-release-key.jks" and second-release-key.jks info.

Comment: Just to be clear, what you're trying to do is switch to a newer signing key without breaking the ability to update your app, right? Because (AFAIK) that's the only purpose for using multiple signers right now. The v3 signature block will contain some information that lets newer Android versions verify that all signers are part of the same signer lineage, but `verify` might only show the last signer in the lineage. If you use `--min-sdk-version 26` together with `verify` it might show the older signer, since older Android versions don't support the v3 scheme.

Comment: In other words: for any given signature scheme, your app is only signed by one signer. But in the v3 scheme your app also contains some additional information telling Android _"look, here's proof that I also am the owner of these older signers that I have used for my app in the past, so going forward you should therefore also accept this newer signer for any updates to the app"_. At least that's my understanding of it.

Comment: Problem is our app apk is signed with sha1 signer #1 and sha1 signer #2 using jarsigner. meaning multisigned using both first-release-key.jks and second-release-key.jks which i believe now is wrong. App shows both certs.

Now trying to sign apk with apksigner using sha2 signer #1 and then sha2 signer #2 was failing so my question asked.

Comment: apksigner verify -v --max-sdk-version 27 --print-certs myapk.apk
shows first-release-key.jks certs info.

apksigner verify -v --max-sdk-version 28 --print-certs myapk.apk

shows second-release-key.jks certs info.

apksigner verify -v --min-sdk-version 21 --print-certs myapk.apk
shows second-release-key.jks certs info.(min-sdk-version of myapk is 21).

apksigner verify -v --min-sdk-version 17 --print-certs myapk.apk
error:uses digest algorithm SHA-256 and signature algorithm RSA which is not supported on API Level(s) 17 for which this APK is being verified

Comment: Watch out that the lineage is used for key rotation, not  for signing an APK with two keys. Are you after changing the signing key? Or signing one APK with 2 keys? These are two complete different operations, and from your initial text, it seems that you were after the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.

**1)Get the certificate lineage usign below.**

apksigner rotate --out /path/to/new/file --old-signer \ --ks my.keystore --new-signer --ks mynew.jks

**2)Multi sign using both the certificate passwords.**

apksigner sign --lineage mylineagefile --ks my.keystore --next-signer --ks mynew.jks my.apk

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/apksig/+/refs/heads/master/src/apksigner/java/com/android/apksigner

Answer (score 0):

Try with the flag `--v3-signing-enabled=false`.

As mentioned in the error message, v3 signing does not support signing with multiple keys so I suspect that disabling it would fix this error.

Note that v3 signing is an extension of v2 signing that supports key rotation, so you're not losing in security (well, besides key rotation which you may never be able to use).